# Trouble using Infinite Scroll with an onClick function

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

Sorry for my broken english.
I have infinite scroll  paul irish plugin working with masonry David DeSandros plugin. Everyting is working well until i wanted to add some onclick functions on each elements of my container . My probleme is that on of the onclick function is repeating it self buy x, which x is the number of pages loaded buy scrolling. I guess my probleme is on infinte scrolls callback.

here is the on click function who is not working good

```
 container.find('.appende_playlist').click(function(){
     if (test_click == 0){                       
                var framesrc = $(this).parent().find('iframe:first').attr('src');
                var framesrc2 = framesrc.replace('artwork=false','artwork=true');           
                $('.playlist_players').append("<iframe src="+framesrc2+">");
                test_click++;
                alert('if');                
                }
                else{               
                alert('else');
                }
                });
```

like i said the error is starting while i reache the 3d or 4th page 
here is the hall page

```
 jQuery(function($){
 var test_click = 0;
 var container = $('.conteneur');

    $(window).load(function(){
    container.imagesLoaded(function(){
    container.masonry({
    isAnimated:true, 
    isFitWidth:true,
    isResizable:true,     
    itemSelector: '.blog-block2',
    columnWidth: function( containerWidth ) {
    return containerWidth / 3;            
        }
      });
    });   
   $('body').scrollTo( '1px', 250 );
         });
```

```
 container.infinitescroll({
        navSelector  : '.pager',  
        nextSelector : '.pager a', 
        itemSelector : '.conteneur', 
        bufferPX: 20,
            loading: {
            finishedMsg: '<i>Vous êtes arrivé au bout de Lazyshake! Suivez nous sur facebook.</i>',
        msgText: '<em>Chargement des prochains articles</em>',
        animate: true,  
        img: 'http://i.imgur.com/zfnOQ.gif'         

}},
```

```
// Le Callback Masonry
    function( newElements ) {        
        var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });       
        $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
                  $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
                  container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
                var bloc = container.find('.blog-block2:first'); 
                var cssi = {width:bloc.width()};
                var cssf = null;             
                    container.find('a.thumb').click(function(e){                
                        var elem = $(this); 
                        var cls = elem.attr('href').replace('#','');

                    var fold = container.find('.unfold').removeClass('unfold').css(cssi).css('height','auto'); 
                    fold.stop();
                    var unfold = elem.parent().parent().parent().addClass('unfold').css(cssf).css('width','618'); 
                    container.masonry('reload'); 

                        if(cssf == null){
                            cssf = {
                                width : '618',
                                height: 'auto'
                            };

                        }               
                        unfold.css(cssi).animate(cssf);
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            var eTop = $('.unfold').offset().top- $(window).scrollTop();
                                        //console.log(eTop);
                                 if (eTop <= 250){
                                    $.scrollTo('.unfold', 400, {offset: {top:-150} });
                                 }
                                 else
                                 {
                                    $.scrollTo('.unfold', 400, {offset: {top:-90} });
                                 }
                        },500); 
                         e.preventDefault(); 
    });});
```

here is the website where im working on http://www.lazyshake.com. The function is the "add playlist button" which appears after first click on an image.

hope someone can help me on this , because i acctualy lost 3 days :s